# Blockchaind Node Monitoring and local testnet

Tags: bitcoind, testnet, testing

Im getting my self into blockchain. I have a few newbie questions:

1. I'm Running a few `bitcoind` Daemons on OpenStack VMs. 
   Can i Monitor transactions coming in? Can I log all inputs and outputs and traffic of my daemon?
2. Can anyone point to good documentation regarding creating a testnet, joining testnets?
3. Any documentation to create more currency on local wallet/local testnet and spend currency in an automated way?

Comment: your title contains `blockchaind`, do you mean `bitcoind`?

Comment: Since this is a question and answer platform, we aim to create great question and answer threads. To that end we prefer questions focussed on one topic, as that makes it easier to point people to exactly the content that they are looking for, and much easier to provide comprehensive answers to the question. Please only ask about one topic per question. It seems to me that some of the questions asked here are answered on https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/63138/5406. Please don't ask the same question in different posts.

Answer (score 1):

> Can i Monitor transactions coming in?

Yes. There are a couple of ways to do this.

Personally, I'd use the ZMQ pubsub capability and process the transactions with a separate program by subscribing to the ZMQ endpoint.

> Can i log all in and outputs and traffic of my Daemon?

Yes.

> Can anyone point to good documentation regarding creating a testnet, joining testnets?

You can run your own network using `regtest`.

To learn more about this, I suggest [here](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-examples#regtest-mode).

Unsure what you meant by "joining testnets".

> Any documentation to create more currency on local wallet/local testnet and spend currency in an automated way?

You can create more bitcoins by mining blocks using the general block `bitcoin-cli` command. This is only usable in `regtest`.

If you want bitcoins in `testnet3`, you will need to get them from a faucet or another bitcoin developer.

The regtest guide should contain instructions on how to generate more bitcoins for yourself to test.

To automate the entire process, I'll assume you have some basic scripting skills to invoke `bitcoin-cli` commands.

Comment: by joining testnets i mean: Can one create a local testnet, expose it to the internet and connect different clients to it?

Comment: yes, you can. But that requires tinkering with the network magic, changing the genesis block seed, then that's pretty much your private blockchain which you can add as many peers as you like. You might be able to just do that with regtest, but i've not tried it out.