# How can I get logging information on incoming transactions with bitcoind?

Tags: bitcoind, relay, logging

Im running two Bitcoind Nodes. Is there anyway to log the incoming transactions and the output?

[image]

Comment: Hi plsbenice, Bitcoin.stackexchange.com is not a forum, so replying to answers doesn't work. I've edited your question to remove the broader follow-up question. Please don't broaden your question after answers have been given as this makes previously complete answers not fit your question anymore. Instead, please ask a new question. You may link the previous question in your new question, and add a comment on your previous question or the answers to your previous questions to point people to the new question if it is closely related. For an overview how our site works, please see our [tour].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you run the daemon or the GUI (bitcoin-qt) using the `debug=1` argument, then bitcoin will write a variety of events to the debug.log file, including info about transactions received by your node.

I just ran a test to confirm this. You could follow these steps if you want:

(1) From the terminal window, start bitcoin-qt like this: `$bitcoin-qt -debug=1`

(2) Navigate to the /.bitcoin folder: `$cd .bitcoin`

(3) View the last few recent entries into the debug.log file: `$tail debug.log`

When I did this, I saw the following entry:

```
2017-11-21 12:58:54 AcceptToMemoryPool: peer=3: accepted 4e1a7429f28c7410e177bf3278aca76b6e32e097ed8d87dbd18980de9c23f343 (poolsz 18765 txn, 94644 kB)
```

I then copied the transaction ID and cross-referenced it at blockchain.info:

```
https://blockchain.info/tx/4e1a7429f28c7410e177bf3278aca76b6e32e097ed8d87dbd18980de9c23f343
```

And as expected, it was there as an Unconfirmed Transaction (which makes sense because the log entry mentions "AcceptToMemoryPool", so it sound like my node received a transaction from a peer, and has decided to put it in the mempool - that's just my guess, maybe I'm wrong)

Comment: if running `$bitcoind -daemon` the output will not go to `.bitcoin/debug.log`, I was not sure where it goes, so I left the `-daemon` option out and let the output show in the shell. You can pipe that into a file if you like