# Bitcoin Core Peer Connecting Problems

Tags: bitcoin-core, client, bitcoin-cli

I am trying to get Bitcoin Coin to sync .

I am having problem .

I have tcp port and Udp port setup . Tcp port is inbound 8333 outbound 8333.

But still no peer connection.

I don't know what to do at this point .

Comment: Is your problem that you aren't receiving any incoming connections, or are no outgoing connections made either?

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know what to do at this point.

I would look at the log files for clues. The location of the log files depends on your operating system and can also be set in the configuration file.

See [How can I get logging information on incoming transactions with bitcoind?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/63138/13866) and Andrew Chow's [Bitcoin Core Troubleshooting FAQ](https://achow101.com/2016/07/Bitcoin-Core-Troubleshooting)